# Xcode new update - reuse indentifer issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have updated my Xcode to 11.4 version after updating I got an error whole of my project.

Did anyone face the same issue and how can I fix it? What is the difference between previous version?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add extra extension like this

```
public extension UITableViewCell {
    static var reuseIdentifier: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have:

```swift
static let reuseIdentifier: String = "REUSE_IDENTIFIER"
```

in your `DriverCell` class

the issue explains that you either don't have it, or the type of it is `String?`

Comment: static var reuseIdentifier: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self)
    }

Comment: that's what I have